# Preserving of energy and partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

So I have the following problem:

we have an equation:

$$ \frac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}(t,x)-u_{xx}(t,x)+q(x)u(t,x)=0 $$

with the following conditions:

$$ u(0,x)=g(x), u_t(0,x)=h(x) $$
and
$$ u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0 $$

and I have to show that the solution preserves the energy

$$ E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} (c^{-2}u_t(t,x)^2+u_x(t,x)^2+q(x)u(t,x)^2)dx $$

So firstly I calculated:
$$\frac{\mathrm{dE} }{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}[c^{-2}u_t(t,x)^2+u_x(t,x)^2+q(x)u(t,x)^2]=\int_{0}^{1}[\frac{1}{c^{2}}u_{tt}u_t+u_xu_{xx}+q(x)uu_t]dx$$

So I assumed because $$ u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0 $$
That then follows $$\Rightarrow u_x(t,0)=u_x(t,1)=0 $$

Then if we insert all of it into our integral together with our equation we get:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{dE} }{\mathrm{d} t} = \int_{0}^{1}[u_tu_{xx}-q(x)u_tu+u_xu_{xt}+q(x)uu_t]dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(u_tu_x)dx=u_t(t,1)u_x(t,1)-u_t(t,0)u_x(t,0)=0-0=0 $$

**My Problem:**

Is this statement correct or I made worng implication:

$$ u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0 \Rightarrow u_x(t,0)=u_x(t,1)=0?$$

Comment: Actually, $u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0 \implies u_t(t,0)=u_t(t,1)=0$

Comment: Oh my mistake... I wante to write $u_t$... Can you explain to me why does it imply?

Comment: Well, the function $u(t,0)$ is constant with respect to $t$. So the derivative with respect to $t$ is 0.